# Remove leading zero form month C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having trouble to remove the leading zero from a date I found this on the miscrosoft website.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 8, 18);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("(M) MMM, MMMM", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
// Displays (8) Aug, August
```

Totally doesn't work here.

This is my code:

```
string date = '2013-04-01'
DateTime billrunDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
string test = billrunDate.ToString("M");
```

Test is now `01 April`

I just need it to be `4` in a string or int idc
Thanks!

Edit if I do:

```
billrunDate.ToString("(M)");
```

I get `(4)`, but I dont need `()`

EDIT 2:
Well this works

```
string test = billrunDate.ToString(" M ");
string testTwo = test.Trim();
```

Very very ugly

Comment: If all you're interested in, is the month value, you could also simply call `billrunDate.Month.ToString()`

Comment: I get the date in a string from another page can change anything about this. That's why I convert a string in a date.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's interpreting `M` as a [standard date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for "month day pattern".

To interpret a single character pattern as a [custom date and time pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), just prefix it with `%`:

```
string test = billrunDate.ToString("%M");
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. I was going to suggest [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx), though I guess OP only wants the month.

Answer (score 4):

One of my most referenced MSDN pages is the [Custom Date & Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page.  You can use these as part of the formatting passed in to the ToString() method.  If any of them are standard formatting patterns (as "M" is) and you want to use them along, you have to preface them with '%' or have a space before or after them in the format string (so use "%M", " M", or "M " instead of "M").

Relevant section:

**"M"**

The month, from 1 through 12.

**"MM"**

The month, from 01 through 12.

**"MMM"**

The abbreviated name of the month.

**"MMMM"**

The full name of the month.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert to string the date to retrieve the month number.
Just read the [Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.month.aspx) property of the DateTime class:

```
string date = "2013-04-01";
DateTime billrunDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
string test = billrunDate.Month.ToString();
```