# How to convert date to 104 format without zero in month using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example have query :

```
declare @date datetime = '2014-06-18'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,@date,104)
```

Response is : 18.06.2014 , but I want month without zero, it should be like : 18.6.2014 is it possible to do something like this ?

Comment: IMHO, no possible. 104 format is DD.MM.YYYY. It can be useful about your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973716/remove-leading-zero-form-month-c-sharp

Comment: Just out of interest, where will you use this value and what is the actual reason for not wanting the extra 0?

Comment: @Tanner in table i have data something like this : 24566785*18.7.2014 and 52166785*19.06.2014 , in stored procedure call have value date datetime which ecual for example : '2014.7.18'. i want select data from table where date like '%52166785*18.07.2014%' . but logic not work because when i convert it to 104, response is with zero but in table i have without zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It feels a little "kludgy", but the only place the sequence `.0` can appear in the output date (assuming you're working with dates after 1000 A.D., which you are for `datetime` which cannot represent dates before 1753) is when there's a leading `0` on the month. So:

```
declare @date datetime = '2014-06-18'
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,@date,104),'.0','.')
```

Produces:

```
18.6.2014
```

Answer (score 6):

```
declare @date datetime = '2014-06-18'


SELECT CAST(DAY(@date)   AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.' +  
       CAST(MONTH(@date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.' + 
       CAST(YEAR(@date)  AS VARCHAR(4)) 

RESULT:  18.6.2014
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above you can use the CONCAT function:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2014-06-18'
SELECT
CONCAT(DAY(@date),'.',MONTH(@date),'.',YEAR(@date))
```

This will return 18.6.2014

Also, if you want to strip the leading zero of the day (say for 2014-06-06), this will take care of that too (which damien_the_unbeliever's solution will not.  Not that it is wrong, the behavior is just different so I wanted to make the distinction since it wasn't explicitly stated)

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515(v=sql.110).aspx